# How to export table that has an encrypted column

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has a column (lets call it amount). When we insert data to this table, we make use of a trigger to encrypt the data in the amount column using dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Encrypt.

When I export the table to a dmp file and import it in another schema, some data in this column appears to be truncated and cannot be decrypted.

While attempting to decrypt this column the following is the error i get

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28232: invalid input length for obfuscation toolkit
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI", line 84
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT", line 255
ORA-06512: at "USER.DECRYPT3DES", line 9
```

I used the "exp" command to export the table. Is there any other means of exporting the table to a dump file?

Thanks

Comment: The encryption function either produces a RAW or a VARCHAR2. In either case, once the data is encrypted it is a regular column that behaves as all other columns. It should be imported/exported without truncation. Can you provide us with a small example (create table, insert, exp then failed imp)?

Comment: Are you importing into a database with a different character set than the source with a VARCHAR2 column holding the encrypted data?

Comment: @Justin Cave. The database I am exporting from has a character set of AL32UTF8 and so does the database I am importing to.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat The below are examples of create table, insert and trigger - create table submission (REFID VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL, STATEID VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, AMOUNT VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL)       insert into submission values('TEST00119970525737G','ILLINOIS','100');                     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "USER".SUBMISSION_EDINS
before INSERT on SUBMISSION for each row begin :new.AMOUNT := encrypt3des(:new.AMOUNT); end TESI_STAMPSUBMISSION_3des;

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the character set of both the databases, but also the NLS_LANG parameter of the databases and the CLIENTS (source and destination).

Check the HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_xxxxx_Home folder on the registry.

Comment: I checked the Character set of both the DBs and both of them are AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 (i.e. from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS). However I did find a log file relating to the dmp that mentions the following -    import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)    export client uses US7ASCII character set (possible charset conversion)     So could this mean that the NLS_LANG parameters of the DBs are not appropriately set?

Comment: The problem is the client uses US7ASCII. Where are you running the export from, Windows or Unix? If it's Windows go check the NLS_LANG on the registry key I pointed out, but ON THE CLIENT MACHINE, if it's Linux then set the environment variable accordingly, also on the client machine. What are the database and client versions?